# How to convert month in String to month in DateTime?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I am displaying all the months name in Dropdown List, the values are stored in List of Strings.

```
final List<String> _months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
];
```

User can select any value and based on that, I want to convert it to numerical month like if the month is March, the numerical value will be 3. Of course, there are ways to do this without using DateTime at all but I want to do a few other things after converting it to DateTime.

DateTime's `parse` method only takes in a few specific formats and those formats do not include a simple month string like March.

Using the `intl` package, any DateTime can be converted to display numerical month number using

```
DateFormat.M().format(DateTime.now())
```

But it can only be done if the string I am getting such as "December" can be converted to DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a `DateTime` with the month

```
  final selected = _months[2];

  DateTime(2020, _months.indexOf(selected) + 1);
```

Comment: I don't have the index like 3. I only have access to strings like February, August, November etc..

Comment: I have a dropdown list with all 12 months and the user selects the dropdown item. User could select July or the user could select December. The value of dropdown isn't number, it is same as the display value. Of course I could create a map with key as numbers and value as string text but that is not something I want to do unless that is the only way.

Comment: `DateTime(2020, _months.indexOf(selected = "March") + 1);`